# How should I display scale or axes in a different canvas in chart js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to display both the axis on different canvases.
What I am doing currently is, I have created a table of 2*2. (0,0) field in the main charting area. (0,1) field is what I want to be the y-axis and (1,0) field should be x-axis.

```
<table class="stock_chart" id="stk_crt">
                <tr class="stock_chartnprice">
                    <td class="stock_graph" id="can_con">
                        <div class="chart_wrapper" id="chart_wrapper">
                            <canvas id="main_chart"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="axis y_axis">
                        <div class="price_bar" id="price_bar_id">
                            <canvas id="price_bar_canvas"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="time_axis">
                    <td class="axis x_axis">
                        <div class="time_bar" id="time_bar_id">
                            <canvas id="time_bar_canvas"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nil">
                        <div class="nan"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

: HTML code

```
async function chartit(){
    await fetchData();
    var data ={
        datasets:[{
            data:each_data,
        }]
    };

    var options = {
        onResize: resize(),
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins:{
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                grid:{
                    drawBorder:false,
                    display: true,
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: false,
                    callback: function(val, index) {
                        return val;
                },
                },
                position: 'right',
            },
            x:{
                type: 'time',
                display:false,
                grid:{
                    display: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    callback: function(val, index) {
                        if(!(index%5))return val;
                    },
                    },
            }
        },
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'candlestick',
        options: options,
        data: data
    });
}
```

:JS code

In this, I want to add the scale or axes of the graph in *price_bar_canvas* and *time_bar_canvas* .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems like you tried adding pictures but forgot to add the sources/upload them. Also please add the code you already have so far

Comment: @LeeLenalee I've added the code and since I am new to StackOverflow I cant add images rn.